# SharePoint 2010 Workflow: Change Item Not Starting Workflow Over

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am trying to get a workflow to start over when an item is changed even if it is still running on previous criteria. When I changed an item's expiration date, it was set still in pause mode based on the criteria below. Is there a way I can start a workflow over again even if it is in a previously pause stage in the workflow? 
Thanks for any help in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

Multiple instances(for same version) of the same workflow cannot run on a single item at the same time.

If you want to wait for some field to change to the particular value in your workflow then you can use **Wait for Field Change in Current Item** action in SharePoint designer workflow 2013.

**Reference**:

1. [Understanding Eventing Actions in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/understanding-eventing-actions-in-sharepoint-designer).